# Copying and Pasting File paths in Ubuntu / PopOS

Tags: nautilus, files, directory

I am not able to find a solution to copying and pasting paths when saving a file or while opening a file using Nautilus. I am comparing it with the method used in Windows. On Ubuntu / PopOS I am not able to paste the file path when I am saving or opening a file in a software. It becomes quite a task to open the destination folder every time for saving or opening files.

[File Manager on PopOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuNJi.png)

[File Manager on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeKsa.png)

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on the file in file-manager, choosing 'Move to ...' ?
Or choose 'Copy' or 'Cut' and navigate to the location where you want copy / move the file to ?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: Change the defaults to show path (*what is possible varies on the version of `nautilus` you're using & you didn't give release details*), OR if unhappy with that file-manager, select & use another as there are **many** choices; some will be more efficient on resources on a GTK environment (GNOME/Ubuntu) than others but you didn't give us that environment (release matters!)  I'd just ^A on the path line (*when displayed unlike your picture*)

Answer (score 1):

### How to type a location in Nautilus

1. Click on the location (like "Home"). There will be NO feedback.

[image]

2. Simply start typing the full path. `/home/$YOU/something`. Now you get feedback.

[image]

3. Hit `<Enter>`. And look what happens:

[image]

---

### How to copy a location in Nautilus

1. Use the Current Folder Menu

[image]

2. Select `Copy Location`

[image]

The location is saved to the clipboard as plain text. You can paste that text into any application (including back into Nautilus). Here, let's paste it into a Text Editor:

[image]

---

### How to paste a location into Nautilus

There are THREE tricks to pasting into Nautilus, but you already know two of them:

- Clicking on the location bar (without feedback)
- Using full paths
- (NEW) Input must start with a keyboard character

1. Let's begin by copying a full path from a text editor:

[image]

2. Click on the location bar (again, NO feedback)

[image]

3. Type a character. Let's randomly choose `G`. Whoa, it changed into a Search box!

[image]

4. Delete the G, then paste (CTRL+v) the path. The search box turns back into a location.

[image]

5. Finally, hit `<Enter>`

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the detailed response. I really appreciate it. I am aware of Ctrl+L and I use it wherever I can. The image I have attached shows that there is no address/ directory bar when saving or opening a file inside an application. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: Oh, you specified Nautilus in your question, so that's what I answered. On the Open/Save dialogs I tested from several stock Ubuntu 23.04 applications, it works exactly the same way. Please open a new question with a bit more clarity on exactly what's not working, preferably with enough step-by-step detail so we can reproduce it in a test environment.

Comment: How is it possible that the "Copy location" option is not available to me in the context menu you shop on point 2)?? I can't also click on the path to edit edit...

Comment: @Pere Please open a new question with full details. Comments on this answer should be about improving this answer, not to an apparently unrelated new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the location by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>